# Python condition base print color string

Tags: python, linux, colors, scripting

Here is last part of python script, where i am printing following values.

```
for i in data:
        print i[2], '|', i[12], '\t|', i[24].split('@')[-1], '\t|' , i[9]
```

Output:

```
[root@tux work]# ./fs.py
2015-04-24 11:53:31 | RINGING   |       N/A            | 15035205973
2015-04-24 11:53:31 | DOWN      |       N/A            | 00100017063156582
2015-04-24 11:53:33 | RINGING   |       N/A            | 19516828036
2015-04-24 11:53:00 | ACTIVE    | 72.xx.xx.120         | 19093929436
2015-04-24 11:53:05 | ACTIVE    | 72.xx.xx.120         | 13372528024
```

I am trying to implement `color text` printing using above table status column `RINGING`, `ACTIVE`, `DOWN`

`i[12]` holding status column

```
if RINGING = 'Yellow'
if ACTIVE  = 'Green'
if DOWN    = 'Red'
```

I found following post which is really good but don't know how it will fit in `for` loop

[Python Print Color Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

Comment: If you want more control over terminal output, you could take a look at the [blessings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dict to hold the colors:

```
COLORS = {"RINGING": '\033[93m', "ACTIVE": '\033[92m', "DOWN": '\033[91m', "ENDC": '\033[0m'}
```

Then just do something like:

```
for i in data:
    print COLORS[i[12]],
    print i[2], '|', i[12], '\t|', i[24].split('@')[-1], '\t|' , i[9],
    print COLORS["ENDC"]
```

Comment: Superb! but its working, but its printing `newline` between each line, How do i remote that?

Comment: I figured out, i did this `print i[2], '|', COLORS[i[12]], i[12] + bcolors.ENDC + '\t|', i[24].split('@')[-1], '\t|' , i[9]`